# Multithread message send on TCP server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcpclient

I need to make a broadcast of the clients connected to the server using `TcpClient`. Currently I have a for that goes through the whole list of clients and they receive the message one by one. But there is some time between messages, so the clients do not receive the message simultaneously. I think that using a multithreading or coroutines works, someone can advise me? I attach the function code of the broadcast

Thank you all

```
public void broadCast(string sendMsg)
{
    foreach (User user in clientList)
    {
        if (user.tcpClient != null)
        {
            m_NetStream = user.tcpClient.GetStream();

            if (m_NetStream != null)
            {
                byte[] msgOut = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendMsg);
                m_NetStream.Write(msgOut, 0, msgOut.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                ServerLog("Socket Error: Start at least one client first", Color.red);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send to multiple clients simultaneously, I'd suggest using the `Async` variants of [`Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.writeasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_NetworkStream_WriteAsync_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Threading_CancellationToken_). I'd also, as suggested in the comments, move creating the buffer to send out of the loop.

At the moment you don't return from `broadCast` until all of the messages are sent, which I've implemented below as a [`WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-5.0), but that can be skipped or this method made `async` if that's more appropriate.

```
public void broadCast(string sendMsg)
{
    var pendingSends = new List<Task>();
    byte[] msgOut = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendMsg);
    foreach (User user in clientList)
    {
        if (user.tcpClient != null)
        {
            m_NetStream = user.tcpClient.GetStream();

            if (m_NetStream != null)
            {

                pendingSends.Add(m_NetStream.WriteAsync(msgOut, 0, msgOut.Length));
            }
            else
            {
                ServerLog("Socket Error: Start at least one client first", Color.red);
            }
        }
    }
    Task.WaitAll(pendingSends.ToArray());
}
```

(Side note, not sure that error logging is in the right place. I'd have expected it to trigger on `clientList` being empty instead)

Note that I didn't do anything involving threads here - this task seems to be inherently *I/O bound*, limited by how fast we can send data over the network. Introducing more threads wouldn't change that.

Finally, I'll repeat from the comments:

> be aware that TCP is an *endless stream of bytes*, not *messages*. I'm not seeing you do anything to assist the receiver with determining the extent of your message (by e.g. sending the length first, or delimiters, or other message framing techniques)